# If I run out of one type of seeds for a given crop in Dwarf Fortress, can I alter the plot to fill it out?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I noticed that the farming plot I made above ground will tend to fill up only with a certain number of cultivated cells. If I then go into the controls for the plot, go to the current season and then switch it to something else, will the remaining cells (or at least some of them) fill up and come to fruition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the labor to do so, your 'farm' dwarves should fill the rest of the plot with your new seed. What you planted initially will eventually mature, be harvested and then the new seed will be planted in it's place, unless of course you switch to something else or the season changes.

You can even switch a plot mid-season if you aren't out of seeds... for example if you only have a small farm and limited labor to devote to it, but still want a diversity of crops. Note that dwarves already on their way to plant a seed when the crop is changed will still probably finish their job, planting the old seed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really like giving such a short answer, but simply put:

**Yes**